# How to keep autotools artifacts outside of the source tree?

Tags: makefile, build, autotools

Autotools do (does?) a fine job of keeping 'make' artifacts out of the source tree but it leaves its own detritus -- for example 'configure' or the 'm4' files -- in the directory it’s run from.

I've taken the route of copying the configuration files into a disposable build directory, but it is starting to feel like I've come up with a complex hack to do something simple.  I'm hoping someone can help by giving me the right search words or better yet a pointer to a working example of an autotools build with a pristine source tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to keep autotools artifacts outside of the source tree?

You can't.  The Autotools *define* the source tree as being rooted at the directory containing the `configure` script.  Or if you're looking at it from a project maintainer perspective, then the directory containing `configure.ac`, which is where `configure` is also put.

Moreover, the artifacts generated by running the Autotools are intended to be included in project distributions.  I am aware that the idea of excluding these from revision control has gained some traction lately, but to the extent that network-hosted revision control systems have become a distribution mechanism, such exclusion is wrongheaded.  It thwarts one of the key objectives of the Autotools: that you don't need to have the Autotools in order to build the project.

Even with the Autotools being readily available, it is still useful to decouple building the project from building its build system, because the Autotools -- by design -- focus considerably more on building portable build systems than they do on compatibility between Autotools versions.

HOWEVER, although you cannot put `configure` *etc*. outside the source tree, you **can** clean them up fairly readily after a build via `make maintainer-clean`, if you're determined to do so.  That will of course clean all built components, not just the machine-generated build-system components.  But I would recommend instead keeping everything that `make distclean` leaves behind.

Comment: Thank you for the direct answer and the context to go with it.  I had been avoiding shipping a premade set of Makefiles but it seems like that might be the right strategy after all.

Comment: @TimKolar, the makefiles are not among the files I recommended keeping.  These are generated by `configure` and cleaned up by `make distclean`.  Not requiring the Autotools for builds means you don't need to have Autoconf, Automake, Libtool, or their supporting packages.  You must keep their outputs, including `configure`, `Makefile.in` files, `config.h.in`, and similar, but not anything generated by `configure` or `make`.  This is the boundary between project maintainer responsibility and project build responsibility.